# JQuery UI spinner spin event not as expected in Scala JS

Tags: jquery-ui, scala.js

When I define a spinner in ScalaJS and handle the spin value I am not able to get the new spin value in the event as I would have expected. According to the JQuery UI documentation the second parameter to the spin event is the ui object that contains a value attribute. So I defined a trait:

```
trait Number extends js.Object {
    val value: Int = js.native
}
```

And then handle my spin event thus:

```
jQuery("#mySpinner").spinner(js.Dynamic.literal(spin = { (e: HTMLInputElement, ui: Number)  =>
  log("Change: " + ui.value)
  }: js.ThisFunction1[HTMLInputElement, Number, Any]))
```

But the "value" attribute does not seem to be a member of the ui object as I get the exception below in my log statement. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

> uncaught exception: scala.scalajs.runtime.UndefinedBehaviorError: An
>   undefined behavior was detected: undefined is not an instance of
>   java.lang.Integer

Comment: Well obviously `ui` doesn't have a `value` attribute. You should log `ui` itself to see what its shape is.

Comment: I did and it is an [Object] which is what it says in the JQuery UI documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-spin. But it should have a value attribute. How to extract this "value" Number is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You say `e: HTMLInputElement` but it should be `e: Event`

Comment: This is appropriate way to define a js.ThisFunction from what I have read. See: http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is a combination of the previous comments. You are correct that, since you're using ThisFunction, the first element should be an Element of some sort. (Although, is it really an HTMLInputElement? That's a slightly unusual element type to put a spinner on.)

But that Element gets *prepended* to the function parameters, whereas you've got it *replacing* one.

In other words, you have 

`(e: HTMLInputElement, ui: Number)`

but it needs to be

`(elem: HTMLInputElement, e:Event, ui: Number)`

in order to match the expected signature. So in practice, the system is trying to cast the `value` member of an Event, which of course doesn't exist, to Integer. It finds that `value` is undefined, tries to cast it to Integer, and *boom*.

I can't say I'm 100% certain (and IMO that ui parameter is just plain weird to begin with -- I'm a little suspicious of the jQueryUI documentation there), but that's my guess. Try fixing the signature of your call, and see if the error goes away...